# Can we implement web-hook listener in asp.net web services(asmx)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asmx, webhooks

I want to implement web hook listener in my `asp.net web services(asmx)`. I searched a lot about this but couldn't find any solution.
Is it possible?
Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean? Do you want a sample asmx service file that gets information when it is requested by another system?

Comment: Yes. Assuming you meant an endpoint that listens for requests _sent_ to it (for processing), **any** flavor of ASP.Net will do depending on whatever protocol/s are set - `http`? `soap`?

Comment: @Jalal Exactly, that is what I want to achieve.

Comment: Based on your comments to the answers, you seem to be asking someone here to write code for you. The link you provided below is what you should read, understand and work on.

Comment: @EdSF I'm not asking for code. But I'm asking for the way how can receive those data which comes to that method. I haven't mentioned for code in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this way:(e.g. The data coming in was in `JSON` format from server)

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public void WebHookDataRecieve() //This method is called from Amazon Simple Notification Service when we receive a bounce.
{
 string notification = "";
 using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
 {
   var request = HttpContext.Current.Request;
   request.InputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
   request.InputStream.CopyTo(stream);
   notification = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray());//All of your data will be here in JSON format.
   //Simply parse it and access the data.
   }
}
```

This worked.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't test it, But I think the general idea would be like this:

NotifyService.asmx

```
<%@ WebService language = "C#" class = "NotifyService" %>

using System;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

[WebService(Namespace = "http://localhost/")]
public class NotifyService: WebService{

   [WebMethod]
   [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
   public String Notify(string name) 
   {
      return "Hello " + name;
   }
}
```

Then you can call it by requesting `GET http://localhost/NotifyService.asmx/Notify?name=Dude`

Comment: Thank You very much for your answer, but how can I capture data sent by that server when my `URL` gets fetched. Because I want their data which then be processed according to my need.

Comment: I appreciate your help but that is not the solution to my problem. Please see this link: https://chat-api.com/en/?lang=EN. The server can send unlimited data in `JSON` form. It won't be my defined data.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, I am assuming that you only need a reference to resources to get you started? If so:

- ASP.NET WebHooks (https://github.com/aspnet/aspnetwebhooks) is probably the first place to start.
- If you are looking for a basic tutorial on building a WebHook that deals with chat. I would suggest giving this article a read (https://tutorials.botsfloor.com/facebook-chatbot-in-asp-net-2f9379a238b0)

Frankly, I am not sure you put enough effort before asking the question, as a few google searches gave these results quite quickly. There is a lot more resources to help you get started with ASP.NET WebHooks.